# Removing borders of v-autocomplete/v-combobox vuetify 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to remove the borders of v-combobox in vuetify 3. Everything that I tried doesn't seem to be working.

I need to use the outlined version, this is an example:

```
<v-combobox
  label="Combobox"
  :items="['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Texas', 'Wyoming']"
  variant="outlined"
></v-combobox>
```

I tried to target the elements both in my code and in the devtool's inspector and seems like there is a .v-field class for a div rendered that allows me to change the border-radius of the combobox, so I thought that it would be also responsible for removing the borders, but when I try to set the border to none didn't work.

Does anybody have an idea of how I could do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
  .v-field.v-field--variant-outlined .v-field__outline__start,
  .v-field.v-field--variant-outlined .v-field__outline__notch::before,
  .v-field.v-field--variant-outlined .v-field__outline__notch::after,
  .v-field.v-field--variant-outlined .v-field__outline__end {
    border: none;
  }
```

Comment: Works for me in Vuetify 3. Thank you!